# Is it possible to put in Figma unit scale in vw units?

Tags: figma, figma-plugin

The new version of Figma has the ability to use rem units.
To control them, use the set unit scale property.

But this property is specified in `pixels`.

[image]

Is it possible to set unit scale in `vw` units?

It is very important for me.
This would allow layout in relative units of measure. And take values immediately from the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.
Even REM was recently introduced.

There's a [featured request opened in the Figma forums](https://forum.figma.com/t/support-for-relative-font-size-units-vw-vh-c/710) about it, you can try to upvote it.